# angular-leaflet : draw control: GeoJSON of Circle and Point are same. How to differentiate?

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, leaflet.draw

I suppose to save the drawn shapes and on-demand it should load into the map. When I draw `point` and `circle` it gives same geoJSON. Type of both the shapes are `point`. I can't able to differentiate the difference. When I load the `circle` geoJSON to the map, it is loading as `point`.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jpremkumar/9x86F/26/)

Checkout the console log from the screenshot.

[image: leaflet]

Is't a bug or I'm doing something wrong?
Please advice.

Answer (score 2):

GeoJSON doesn't support circles. It's doing the best it can with the point. I got around it by storing the radius as a property of the feature

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, because they can be represented with the same information but **symbolized** differently.

Think of the following: what is the GeoJSON representation of a blue line vs a red line? They are the same, but one is symbolized in blue and the other is symbolized in red.

The same applies to points: you can symbolize a point with a blue circle, or a yellow square, or a blue arrow, or a word. Their data model is the same, their symbolization is different.

Comment: I've problem while saving the GeoJSON. In map we can show as you suggested. But once you saved and retrieve it back. How to differentiate? Bze geometry type of both is `Point`, How can I identity that, this is `circle` and `point`.

Comment: You're using `layer.asGeoJSON()`. Use things like `layer instanceof L.Point` and access `layer.options`.